# Django Save creating two records instead of one

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django is creating two records in MySQL instead of one.

I call a function via a link

```
<a href="{% url 'markpresent' id=c.id %}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Thats Me!</button></a>
```

The function itself is very straight forward.  I take the variable via a request.get, create a new object, and finally save it.  However, when I check the DB there are two records, not just one.

```
def markpresent(request, id):
    new_attendance = attendance(clientid_id = id, date = datetime.datetime.now(), camp = 3)
    new_attendance.save()
    return render(request, 'clienttracker/markpresent.html', {
        'client': id,
    })
```

Model

```
class attendance(models.Model):
    clientid = models.ForeignKey(newclients, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    camp = models.CharField(max_length = 3, default=0)
```

Any help and direction would be appreciated.

**SOLUTION BASED ON ANSWERS**

```
<form action="{% url 'markpresent' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" name="client" value="{{ c.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Thats Me!</button>
</form>

def markpresent(request):
    id = request.POST.get('client')
    new_attendance = attendance(clientid_id = id, date = datetime.datetime.now(), camp = 3)
    new_attendance.save()
    return render(request, 'clienttracker/markpresent.html', {
        'client': id,
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a debug print in def markpresent (any print message)? See how many times it is getting printed in console of runserver

Comment: I'm running this via passenger on a remote server, so runserver is really not an option here.  Any suggestions regarding troubleshooting in the current environment would be appreciated, but with the setup, I can't use runserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid modifying your database on a GET request. Various things could cause a duplicate request - for instance, a request for an asset or favicon being caught by the same URL pattern and routed to the same view - so you should always require a POST before adding an entry in your database.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm settled on the get request since I'm dynamically generating a list of clients based on a query to the db. I guess I may have to use Post here, but then I'm gonna have to deal with multiple submit buttons on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Google Chrome? If yes, then Google Chrome has something like lazy loading. So if you will type your URL in Google Chrome, it will try to load site behind the scenes and if you will tap enter, then you will get this URL again. The same is when you're trying to go over anchor with a link. It's an edge case, but it happens. Try with firefox or disable that function.

Comment: using firefox, but also this highlights potential flaws in the approach based on browser inconsistencies.  Obviously, want app to work with all browsers (as much as possible).

Comment: @PerryDaPlatypus sure, so as Daniel Rosemann wrote, recommended option is to use POST for creation.